# Impossible bid at Pinochle

Tags: bidding, pinochle

If a person bids 43, only has 11 meld, but claims they can take all the tricks is it allowed? There are only 25 tricks and we’ve assumed it would be a set.

Comment: I'm unclear what you’re asking. It sounds like they will go set, but are you asking if there’s a rule against making a bid that’s impossible to win?

Comment: Team bid 43 but only had 11 meld. They felt they should be able to play it because they could take all the tricks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule stating that you cannot make a bid that's impossible to win, or that you cannot proceed to play the hand if your bid is impossible.

Some rule sources have a rule that a player can choose to throw in their hand and not play the trick-taking portion of the hand; others do not have this rule. But even when playing with this rule, it is an optional choice for the winner of the bid; never mandatory.

Now if you are playing with this rule, then a player who cannot make their bid but chooses to play it out anyway is only wasting your time, and I would consider it poor sportsmanship; something I would be annoyed about. They are also risking giving the opponents extra points if they do not manage to capture all 25 points. So the decision to play the hand is strictly worse than throwing in the hand at that point.

In your specific situation, there is not enough information to understand exactly what happened. Did the player explain why they wanted to play the hand? Was it just because they wanted to see if they could manage to capture all 25 points, even though they knew they would go set anyway? Or did they not understand something about the rules that made them think that they could avoid going set?

In a friendly setting, if it was a very relaxed game with everyone having plenty of extra free time to sit around and play the game, then I could see someone asking their opponents if they mind playing the impossible hand just for fun, to see if they are able to take every trick with their hand. But if a player objects and says that they don't have that extra time to spare, then it would be rude to insist on doing it anyway.

In summary, the play is legal, and according to some rule sources even mandatory.